# Html5 Video with Safari 5.0.5 does not work (mp4)

Tags: html, video, safari

I am currently working on a Intranet application where the majority of the users works with Safari 5.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
One of the applications tasks is to show different mp4 videos to the user. I am using the HTML5 video tag for that purpose. 
My web server accepts ranges in order to support streaming.

The Html markup is defined as following:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>

<source src="http://MyHost/MyApp/Resources/TestVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />

<!-- fallback to Flash: -->

<object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf">


    <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />

    <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=over&amp;image=poster.jpg&amp;file=http://MyHost/MyApp/Resources/TestVideo.mp4" />

    <!-- fallback image -->

    <img src="poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" 

         title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />

</object></video>
```

IE9 and Chrome play that video without a problem.
However, Safari 5.0.5 on Mac OS X does not play it at all. It just doesn't do anything. Surprisingly Safari 5.0.5 on Win32 plays the video without a problem. Unfortunately - for some reason I haven't figured out yet - the "Network" pane of Safaris WebInspector is not available. Hence I cannot dig deeper into what is going on right now. I am not an expert when it comes to Mac OS X... so maybe someone can give me a hand here.

Any hint is appreciated.

TH

Comment: Is QuickTime installed on the Mac you're testing on?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a very old question but I had the exact problem you did and spent a lot of time finding this fix:

Make sure the `<source>`'s `src` is a full URL, not a relative one.  For some reason a `src` like `http://example.com/video.mp4` works in Safari 5.0.5/OS X 10.6.8 but not `/video.mp4`.

There does not seem to be a reason for this whatsoever.  It's just a browser bug.